# Firebase. Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, gitlab, fastlane

Faced with the next problem, maybe who can tell.
I have two hosts, with two runners. On one of them, I already had CI configured and the Firebase assembly is working there. I set up another host (second) to build, essentially all the same configurations, on it I got a new token for firebase, but when I try to run my CI on the second host, I have a job drop. I read forums and official documentation, in search of a solution to the problem, but they did not fit my case.

```
[12:47:16]: ---------------------------------------
[12:47:16]: --- Step: firebase_app_distribution ---
[12:47:16]: ---------------------------------------
[12:47:19]: ▸ i  getting app details...
[12:47:19]: ▸ Error: failed to fetch app information. Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid. Please run firebase login --reauth
[12:47:19]: ▸ For CI servers and headless environments, generate a new token with firebase login:ci
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                Lane Context                                                                 |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM                    | android                                                                                               |
| PLATFORM_NAME                       | android                                                                                               |
| LANE_NAME                           | android firebase_dev                                                                                  |
| GRADLE_ALL_APK_OUTPUT_PATHS         | ["C:/Users/_/Android/application/build/outputs/apk/psb_dev_test/debug/_  |
|                                     | 722.1-debug.apk"]                                                                                     |
| GRADLE_ALL_AAB_OUTPUT_PATHS         | []                                                                                                    |
| GRADLE_ALL_OUTPUT_JSON_OUTPUT_PATHS | []                                                                                                    |
| GRADLE_ALL_MAPPING_TXT_OUTPUT_PATHS | []                                                                                                    |
| GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH              | C:/Users/_/Android/application/build/outputs/apk/psb_dev_test/debug/_  |
|                                     | 2.1-debug.apk                                                                                         |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[12:47:19]: Shell command exited with exit status 1 instead of 0.
i  getting app details...

Error: failed to fetch app information. Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid. Please run firebase login --reauth

For CI servers and headless environments, generate a new token with firebase login:ci


+------+---------------------------------+-------------+
|                   fastlane summary                   |
+------+---------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                          | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform                | 0           |
| 2    | clean assemblePsb_dev_testDebug | 682         |
|    | firebase_app_distribution       | 3           |
+------+---------------------------------+-------------+

+---------------------------+--------------+----------------+
|                 Plugin updates available                  |
+---------------------------+--------------+----------------+
| Plugin                    | Your Version | Latest Version |
+---------------------------+--------------+----------------+
| firebase_app_distribution | 0.1.4        | 0.2.5          |
+---------------------------+--------------+----------------+
[12:47:19]: To update all plugins, just run
[12:47:19]: $ bundle exec fastlane update_plugins

[12:47:19]: fastlane finished with errors

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

Could not access the GitHub API, you may have better luck via the website.
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=Shell command exited with exit status 1 instead of 0.
i  getting app details...

Error: failed to fetch app information. Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid. Please run firebase login --reauth

For CI servers and headless environments, generate a new token with firebase login:ci
&type=Issues&utf8=✓
Traceback (most recent call last):
        30: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
        29: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
        28: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
        27: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:122:in `take_off'
        26: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
        25: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:352:in `run'
        24: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
        23: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in `run!'
        22: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
        21: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
        20: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
        19: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        18: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
        17: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
        16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
        15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
        14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
        12: from Fastfile:68:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
        11: from Fastfile:83:in `deploy'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
         9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
         8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `execute_action'
         7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `chdir'
         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in `block in execute_action'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
         4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution-0.1.4/lib/fastlane/plugin/firebase_app_distribution/actions/firebase_app_distribution_action.rb:36:in `run'
         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:80:in `sh_control_output'
         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in `method_missing'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.172.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:153:in `shell_error!': [!] Shell command exited with exit status 1 instead of 0. (FastlaneCore::Interface::
FastlaneShellError)
i  getting app details...

Error: failed to fetch app information. Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid. Please run firebase login --reauth

For CI servers and headless environments, generate a new token with firebase login:ci
```

Also in my company, I have a proxy that blocks access to various resources.
What I tried:

1. Added environment variable for proxy http_proxy=... https_proxy=
2. Added environment variable set "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0"
3. Tried to do
   firebase login --reauth
   firebase login:ci
   Getting a token without a problem.

I may have missed something, but so far I have not been able to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: As it turned out in the project itself, proxy was configured in the Fastfile, with a .pem key. After deleting the two rows proxy_settings and proxy_cert_path. The article was loaded successfully.